# Xamarin Visual Studio iOS Portable Class Library rebuild process

Tags: ios, xamarin, visual-studio-2013, portable-class-library

I have a PCL in my Xamarin iOS project.  Working from VS, I am finding that to get a change to the PCL reflected in the iOS app, I have to do all of the following:

- Kill the app from VS
- Quit the app in the simulator
- Delete the app from the simulator
- Rebuild the PCL in VS
- Finally, build and run the iOS project.

Can I simplify this workflow?  I do have a build dependency from the iOS project to the PCL project.  But it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: This looks pretty much like some bug with how we track dependencies.  A change in one of the referenced projects should really trigger a recompilation.

Comment: Entirely possible.  My experience with dependencies in native iOS (i.e. Xcode, no Xamarin) has been that dependencies have a lot of non-obvious behavior, especially nested dependencies.  If A links to B and B links to C, it does not follow that A links to C.  I can imagine that it gets that much more confusing when you have VS on top of it.

Comment: Are you using the Xamarin Mac Pairing then? I've had issues where the pairing breaks WITHOUT warning during a build and the changes aren't reflected. However I just make sure the pair is complete every-time I start working on my project again.

Comment: Yes, over WiFi.  But the problem happens every time.  So I don't think it's some flaky-connection type of problem.

Answer (score 5):

Have you checked your build configuration? I had this same issue a few weeks ago and it was because certain projects were not being built in the active configuration. My PCL libraries were not being built by default.

Build menu -> build configuration